# Define type for wrapping library function

Tags: typescript

I’m trying to learn TypeScript but have an issue that I struggle to resolve.

```js
function makeClient(api, kubeconfig: string) {
  const config = new k8s.KubeConfig()

  if (kubeconfig) {
    config.loadFromFile(kubeconfig)
  } else {
    config.loadFromCluster()
  }

  return config.makeApiClient(api)
}
```

I need to create a function that wraps another function from a library ([Kubernetes client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kubernetes/client-node)), what I want to do is to allow two arguments to my function: `api` and `kubeconfig`. 
If `kubeconfig` is set, I will create a client for the given `api` argument using the given file. 
If `kubeconfig` is not set or empty/null, I will create an in-cluster client for the given `api`.

My issue is that I somehow need to provide a type for the `api` parameter. The library provides some types, but when I look at the types of the `makeApiClient` function argument, I get this:

```js
export declare class KubeConfig {
  // ...
  makeApiClient<T extends ApiType>(apiClientType: ApiConstructor<T>): T;
  // ...
}
export interface ApiType {
    defaultHeaders: any;
    setDefaultAuthentication(config: api.Authentication): void;
}
declare type ApiConstructor<T extends ApiType> = new (server: string) => T;
```

How should I provide a type to my `api` argument so that it allows only supported values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make your wrapping function also generic? Then you can just use the type that is expected by `makeAPICLient`. Like this:

```js
function makeClient<T extends k8s.ApiType>(api: k8s.ApiConstructor<T>, kubeconfig: string | null): T {
  const config = new k8s.KubeConfig()

  if (kubeconfig) {
    config.loadFromFile(kubeconfig)
  } else {
    config.loadFromCluster()
  }

  return config.makeApiClient(api)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I’m new to TypeScript, I don’t know what a generic type is '^^ I tried to add `declare type ApiConstructor<T extends k8s.ApiType> = new (server: string) => T` to my code and use your types but then I get two new issues: for `api` arg type => Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'ApiType'. / for return statement => Type 'ApiType' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'ApiType'.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed the `extends` part. Does the edited answer work for you? You shouldn't need to copy any definitions. Just import them.

Comment: Indeed this works! Sadly, the `ApiConstructor` type is not exported by the library, so I still need to copy its definition… Thanks for your kind help, I really need to get more familiar with TypeScript!